# Looking for Tronk the kids TV robot 1960s/1970s

Tags: story-identification, tv

As stated in the title I'm looking for a robot featured in a kids UK TV series in the late 60s/early 70s.

It was (I think) live action in a studio with a cartoon cutaway to whatever Tronk was up to this week....."Tronk is being a dog, good boy Tronk"

I remember watching this in b&w but it was about 1975 before my parents upgraded to a colour television

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is surely *[Mr Trimble](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5655414/)*, a children's programme produced by Yorkshire Television, and shown at lunchtime from 1972 - 1977.

From [nostalgia central](https://nostalgiacentral.com/television/tv-by-decade/tv-shows-1970s/mr-trimble/):

> This 20-minute Yorkshire Television children’s programme was a mixture
> of live actors and puppets, with live action and film.
>
> Mr Trimble (a cross between Dr Who and Mr Pastry) lived in the attic
> of a house with his talking goldfish Glug and his magic telescope
> through which he would watch short educational films.
>
> Downstairs in the house lived a pop group comprising Peter, Paul and
> Jim, who would pop up to sing with Mr Trimble.

Not mentioned is the cartoon robot, Tronk. He can be seen at about the 11 minute mark in this [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xb3jb5hqb-Y) sample.

[image: Tronk, the cartoon robot from "Mr Trimble"]